# Future and Recurring Notifications

Tags: flutter, dart

Can we schedule notifications in Flutter to start firing sometime in Future and also be recurring like for eg reminding a user to take medicines from 6th march 9:00 AM and then everyday on 9:00 AM and the date and time currently is 3rd March 10:00 AM?

If I do this with [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) `zonedSchedule` method then the notification will fire from 4th March 9:00 AM which I don't want.

Is there any other method to do this or any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show schedule notifications without a full screen intent. You can use flutter_local_notificatoin or awesome_notifications packages.

//for repeating:
This package is for creating and parsing recurrence rule. [rrule package flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/rrule)

**[A playground for rrule](https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/)**

You need to create a Model class for alarm e.g.

```
class Alarm{
   final int id;
   final String title;
   final String startDate;
   final String rrule;
   final String endDate; // When you want to repeat until a specific date
 }
```

The recurrence rule for daily repeating -> **RRULE:FREQ=DAILY**,

You have a start DateTime (6 March 2023).

```
final startDate = DateTime(2023, 03, 06).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

Schedule the notification based on startDate.

When you schedule the notification save the alarm in local database.

When the notification occurs you'll receive a callback in Android (only) devices.
//Note: In iOS device there's no callback when the app is closed.

By using that callback you can get the alarm's startDate and recurrence rule from local database.

Now you have startDate and rrule for the alarm ->  Use them with the [rrule](https://pub.dev/packages/rrule) you can get the next dateTime for scheduling the next notification.

Overall Steps:

1. Schedule a notification and store data in local database.
2. When the notification occurs get the data from local database. (store in a variable) e.g.

   var **alarmFromDB** = Alarm(id: 1, title: "medicine", startDate: 1677817922360, rrule: "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY");
3. Clear that data from local database because the next instance of dateTime need to be stored with same Id, So that we can get the instance for third time scheduling.
4. Now by using **alarmFromDb** you can pass startDate and recurrence rule to the rrule package and get the next instance (dateTime for next occurring).
5. Schedule the notification with that instance and update the startDate in **alarmFromDB** and store in local database again.

Comment: I have a couple of questions - 
1 - What if the notification from database didn't show up because the mobile was switched off or the notifications were paused for the app or system wide.
2 - What if I want to achieve this in iOS too?

Comment: Answer 1: You need to code natively (create notification using alarm manager and store data in local db) and in Android we have broadcast receivers which helps to receive a callback when the device is restarted. Use that callback to get data from local db then follow from the step 3.
In flutter we have method channels to call native code or use https://pub.dev/packages/pigeon for typeSafe calls.----
Answer 2: In iOS we need to tap on notification every time it appears then we have a callback and app will open then you can get next instance and schedule next notification.

Comment: It'll be good if you use native code for android and flutter_local_notification/awesome_notifications plugin for iOS